# Hiding a JSF Label Based on condition..!

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean

I have JSF text box like this

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{msgs['label.responsible']}:" for="printingResponsibleEdit"
                                rendered="#{b2cOrderDetailBean.b2cActionOrderView.canChangePrintingInfo() and 
                                                   b2cOrderDetailBean.b2cActionOrderView.showExecutionInfo}" />
                            <h:panelGroup id="printresponsible"
                                rendered="#{b2cOrderDetailBean.b2cActionOrderView.canChangePrintingInfo() and 
                                                  b2cOrderDetailBean.b2cActionOrderView.showExecutionInfo}">
                                <p:inputText id="printingResponsibleEdit" value="#{b2cOrderDetailBean.b2cActionOrderView.printingResponsiblePersNr}" size="4"
                                    valueChangeListener="#{b2cOrderDetailBean.changeListenerString}" required="true" immediate="true"
                                    requiredMessage="#{msgs['msg.required']}" binding="#{printingResponsibleBinding}" maxlength="4">
                                <f:attribute name="historyTypeCode" value="PR" /> 
                                </p:inputText>
                                <h:outputText value=" " />
                                <p:commandButton value="#{msgs['button.ok']}" immediate="true" process="printingResponsibleEdit"
                                    actionListener="#{b2cOrderDetailBean.requestPrintingResponsible}" escape="false"
                                    update="printingResponsibleName printingResponsibleEditMsg">
                               <f:attribute name="printingResponsible" value="#{printingResponsibleBinding.localValue}" /> 
                                <f:param name="responsiblePersonName" value="#{b2cOrderDetailBean.b2cActionOrderView.printingResponsiblePersNr}"></f:param>
                                </p:commandButton>
                                <h:outputText id="printingResponsibleName" value=" #{b2cOrderDetailBean.b2cActionOrderView.printingResponsible}" />
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            <p:message id="printingResponsibleEditMsg" for="printingResponsibleEdit" />
```

And i have my managed beans method like this

```
public void requestPrintingResponsible(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        try {
            b2cActionOrderView.setPrintingResponsible(null);
            b2cActionOrderView.setPrintingResponsibleName(null);
            b2cActionOrderView.setPrintingResponsiblePersNr(null);
            String persNr = (String) actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("printingResponsible");
            if (persNr != null) {
                Account account = accountDelegate.findByPersNr(persNr, localeView.getLocale());
                b2cActionOrderView.setPrintingResponsible(account.getAccountId());
                b2cActionOrderView.setPrintingResponsibleName(account.getName());
                b2cActionOrderView.setPrintingResponsiblePersNr(account.getPersNr());
                validatedPrintingResponsible = account.getPersNr();

                                } else {
                b2cActionOrderView.setPrintingResponsible(null);
            }
        } catch (NoDataFoundException e) {
            LOG.warn("PersNr not found.", e);
            b2cActionOrderView.setPrintingResponsible(null);
            b2cActionOrderView.setPrintingResponsibleName(null);
            b2cActionOrderView.setPrintingResponsiblePersNr(null);
            MessageUtil.addFacesMessage("msg.notFound", colruyt.giftactionmgmt.util.Constants.MSG_PACKAGE, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                    false, "form:tabView:printingResponsibleEdit", null);
        }


    }
```

My problem is when i enter a value that is there in the db and after that if i press ok button the corrensponding user name and user id is displayed but after that if i clear the value in the text box and if i press ok button must be filled error message is coming but the previous lable is not getting cleared.
ie(username,user id).
I have tried in many ways to achieve this can you guys help me

Comment: Where exactly are username and userId h:messages ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is clear `immediate="true"`

When you put `immediate="true"` on your `commandButton` you simply say to JSF please skip any validation on form (including **printingResponsibleEdit**) and process this action (**requestPrintingResponsible**)

So how can JSF validate `printingResponsibleEdit` and render an updated `p:message`(**printingResponsibleEditMsg**) if you have already skipped the validation phase , [See More](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaqq.html) on JSF lifecycle

Put on your mind you have to render(update) every single component you want it to be updated after `Ok` button is pressed or simply you can make `h:panelGroup` container to your component and give it an `ID` and update it ex: `<p:commandButton ... update='containerId'/>`.